# Binomial distribution probability (forming an equality)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The probability that Sally will play football in any week is 0.29. Sally
does not play football more than once in any week. The probability that
Sally play football at least once in a period of $n$ weeks is greater
than 0.98. Find the smallest possible value of $n$.

While working out (using a tree diagram) I ended up with the inequality
$1 - (0.71)^{n} > 0.98$

But the answer says $1 - (0.71)^{n} < 0.98$

I'm not sure if I understand the question at all; any
help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct.

The probability that Sally does not play football in a given week is $1 - 0.29 = 0.71$.  Therefore, the probability that she does not play football in a period of $n$ weeks is $0.71^n$.  The probability that she does play football at least once in a period of $n$ weeks is therefore $1 - 0.71^n$. Since we wish to find the smallest value of $n$ such that the probability that Sally plays football at least once in $n$ weeks is greater than $0.98$, we require that
$$1 - 0.71^n > 0.98$$
as you found.

Let's solve the inequality to verify that your approach is correct.
\begin{align*}
1 - 0.71^n & > 0.98\\
0.02 & > 0.71^n\\
\log_e 0.02 & > n\log_e 0.71
\end{align*}
Since $0.71 < 1$, $\log_e 0.71 < 0$.  Hence, when we divide both sides of the inequality by $\log_e 0.71$, the direction of the inequality reverses, giving
\begin{align*}
\frac{\log_e 0.02}{\log_e 0.71} & < n\\
11.42228817 & < n
\end{align*}

Since we want the smallest number of weeks for which the probability that Sally plays football at least once is greater than $0.98$,
\begin{align*}
\lceil 11.42228817 \rceil & = n\\
12 & = n
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying this.